# Can you send data with a firestore read request?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to give not signed-in users the option to view their data via a token they get sent, that expires after some time.

The token creation and sending part is done and now I see two options: do everything in a function OR use a firestore rule.
Rules would be better though, as a direct database read is faster.

For example, I have a user collection with users looking like this:

```
{
   name: 'test',
   token: '1234',
   expiresAt: <someTimeInFuture>
}
```

and my rules would look like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow get: request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow update: request.auth.uid == userId;

      allow list: if false; 
      allow create, delete: if false;

    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to extend the `get` rule so that users who send that token in their read request can view the data. Or better said: can I send the token with my read request, so that I can view it in the rule?

Keep in mind that a custom claim is not an option, as the user is not signed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security rules do not support the idea that a client can simply send custom data in a request for validation.  That's not actually "secure" at all.  It's like asking someone to provide a password that could be shared anywhere on the internet.  You will need a backend endpoint to do this, but bear in mind that it will also have the same security issue.

Comment: Yeah I know that it is a security concern. Its just about reading data with a requested links. Like multiple companies do with order-status links for example. But thank you for your answer. I will keep this question open in case there is any way, but if not I will accept your answer soon.