# Sending extra (authentication) data with firestore request

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Similar questions (eg. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61758341/can-you-send-data-with-a-firestore-read-request)) have already been asked and answered in negative. I'd like to if any alternatives exist.

I am developing an application where users can collaboratively edit a document. I don't want to force every user to login. I would like to allow users with a link to be able to edit a document (similar to what Google Docs allows). I was planning to share a token in the link which when presented would grant write access. I would have stored the tokens in a separate collection and matched them. But as per previous answers this is not possible and a security issue.

I don't consider it a security concern (for my purposes). The token is like a pre-shared key. Whoever presents the key is allowed access. If the owner thinks that the key is compromised, he can revoke the same. Kindly help me with a way to achieve this. I'm also curious to know how other apps like Google docs achieve this.

Comment: You'll have to route requests through a Cloud function/backend as in the linked answer. Firestore doesn't support passing custom data at the moment.

Comment: @Dharmaraj Thanks. I planning for the same. But  as the previous answer mentions, this method is similarly insecure. I'm wondering how other apps achieve this kind of functionality (perhaps securely)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mentioned by @Dharmaraj,
In Firebase security rules, you have 3 pieces of information, namely the path, the data and the token. Except from those three you can't pass additional information in a security rule.

Cloud Functions would be a better fit here, given the flexibility. Additionally, with Cloud Functions you'd not be forced to authenticate users,  and still be able to connect to Firestore if needed.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying out the spark plan so I was looking for a solution without Cloud Functions. I'll consider using Cloud Functions to solve my problem. For now I'm using batch writes to achieve something similar for 'write' operations.